# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Very strange behavior

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, cors

I have very strange error making request to API. Basically everything worked at the beginning and then suddenly stopped working giving CORS error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: `https://stockx.com/api/products/${url}?includes=market&currency=EUR`,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(json) {
      console.log(json);
    }
});
```

As I said this code worked for me before but now something very strange happened and it started giving me that error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stockx.com/api/products/nike-air-max-1-travis-scott-wheat?includes=market' from origin 'http://hbd.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://stockx.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Then I decided to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to my request but after that error a bit changed to:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stockx.com/api/products/nike-air-max-1-travis-scott-wheat?includes=market' from origin 'http://hbd.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://stockx.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

After all I thought that I got banned on this API due to frequent requests but I can still access this api using my browser or postman.

What would you recommend me to do?

P.S I'm trying to create wordpress plugin, so all script are running under wordpress.

Comment: _"it started giving me that error"_ Perhaps the API in question has been updated to add CORS headers in an attempt to prevent other sites using their data. Adding the header to your requests won't normally have any affect but it seems they are explicitly looking for requests attempting to bypass CORS.

Comment: The API doesn't allow your site to use it. The error message is telling you that whatever may have been the case before, **now** the API is sending back a response that doesn't allow a page on your domain to use the response. The reason the message changed when you added the header to your request (which doesn't make sense, it's a *response* header, not a *request* header) is that it made the request require a preflight (because you had a nonstandard -- and invalid -- header in it), but the fundamental thing didn't change: That API doesn't allow your site to use it.

Comment: It works in Postman because postman doesn't send preflight requests and does not honour the CORS _response_ headers.

Comment: @phuzi,Thanks for your answer but I also tried to change the domain (as I'm using local environment that wasn't big deal) but It also won't help me. So if the problem isn't in domain, then there should be ip block, but then how I can make requests from my browser. I believe there should be way how to bypass this restriction

Comment: What do you mean by "change the domain". Unless the site is running from an allowed domain you won't be able to circumvent the CORS policies from the browser. JavaScript is also restricted in that it can only make AJAX/Fetch requests to the domain from which it was loaded.

Comment: @phuzi, Most likely I incorrectly put it about the domain. Simply put, I have a local environment where wordpress is running and the domain by which I go to the site http://hbd.local, if the api blocks this alias, then I can change it to some other one, for example http://hbd2 .local If the problem is not in this, but in my ip, which is blocked by api, then why can I make a request from the browser if the ip is the same for my browser and site?

Comment: There's a subtle difference between blocking your domain and not allowing other domains. CORS is generally used to _only_ allow requests by a browser from a site on the _same_ domain. It's not that your site's domain has been black-listed, it just hasn't been white-listed.

Comment: @phuzi So is there any way to somehow make this request successful?

Comment: The only way would be to proxy the request from another server so that the data appears to come from the same website or the proxy server allows requests from other domains via CORS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245099/discussion-between-aleksei-c-and-phuzi).

Answer (score -1):

if you want to http request from another website or rest api, you can use serverside rendering. just like go.rice, next.js, go fiber etc. you can google it like how to use server side rendering web application